# ckeditor div background properties

Tags: jquery, html, background, ckeditor

im using ckeditor on my website,
I have some div columns in editor, and i need to change some backgrounds for them. For example into image.

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="title">TITLE</div>
   <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

The problem is all divs have other child divs inside with text, and when im click RMB and "Change div options" its allways going to last child with text, i cannot edit it for top parent... Is there any solution?

I was tried RMB or something in bottom elements path, but there is no effect

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/368/ - but there is not all featured cke, problem is i want change bg image without change in source, just fast click and edit...

Comment: How exactly do you try to change the bg using RMB? Do you have a custom plugin?

Comment: No i dont have any plugin, but i have some other editor, and if you click on elements path right mouse button you can go to element properties, change class style etc... And im searching for ckeditor solution/plugin...

Comment: I mean something like this: http://cutesoft.net/example/general.aspx Please try to click on path element at bottom, it will be great to have it in cke.

Answer (score 0):

A feature like that is not a core feature of CKEditor, but it would be pretty simple to do yourself. I did something like that at my previous job as an event listener extension of CKE. I'd say it would take a decent JS dev just a few days to do something like that - or someone good with CKE and very good at JS a few hours maybe.

My suggestion for the event listening feature

1. Listen to elementspath update event. I recommend using the CKE event, not a native click event, this makes element targeting simpler. See cke docs for event help.
2. On update bind an rmb listener to each elementspath element
3. On rmb, create a small menu DIV with option to edit BG
4. On menuclick, show your custom popup with a BG selector

If you want the feature to be more awesome, you could make it a plugin.

Comment: Ok so i do a plugin, which on RMB click open popup, but is it possible to open for some type of element (a, div), other dialog window? I mean can i get dialog from other default plugins?

Comment: I guess it could be done, I haven't done it myslef so I don't know how to do it though.